# If a cleric wrote a scroll of a spell that a wizard can learn, could a wizard learn the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wizard

When a cleric would write a scroll of a spell that a wizard could cast like  *Protection from Evil and Good*, would the wizard be able to learn the spell from the Cleric scroll?

Comment: Related: [From what items can a wizard learn his spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103260/52137)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### This can work.

Wizards don't *learn* spells; they copy them to their spellbooks and *prepare* them. But besides this small detail, your scenario would work, if the following criteria are met. (This answer assumes that the optional rules for Scribing a Spell Scroll from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* will be followed.)

1. The DM must allow the scribing of spell scrolls.
2. The spell in question must be on both the cleric and wizard spell lists ([*protection from evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good) meets this criterion).
3. The cleric must have proficiency in the Arcana skill.
4. The cleric must have the spell in question prepared.
5. The cleric must spend the necessary downtime and gold to scribe the spell scroll.
6. The wizard must succeed on the necessary Intelligence check to copy the spell from the scroll.
7. The wizard must spend the necessary downtime and gold to copy the spell to their spellbook.

Sources:

1. Scribing a Spell Scroll downtime activity [description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#ScribingaSpellScroll) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* ch. 2
2. Spell scroll magic item [description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) from *Dungeon Master's Guide* ch. 7
3. Wizard spellbook [description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Spellcasting-410) from *Player's Handbook* ch. 3

**Addendum:** Ryan C. Thompson points out that in lieu of the Scribing a Spell Scroll rules from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, the Crafting a Magic Item rules from the *Dungeon Master's Guide* could also be used to create a spell scroll. Those rules would replace my points 3 through 5 above. Both sets of rules are optional and subject to DM allowance.

Comment: It might be better if there was some indication of which sources corresponds with which requirements. Using `<sup>1</sup>` to indicate footnotes might be an idea.

Comment: XGtE is not required. There are also rules for crafting scrolls in the DMG. (Like the crafting rules in XGtE, they are optional.) https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/between-adventures#CraftingaMagicItem

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Thanks. Added addendum.

Answer (score 5):

### A spell on a scroll is on your list or it isn’t

If it is, you can use it.
If it isn’t, you can’t.
How it got to be on a scroll is entirely irrelevant.