# Can a Wizard 14/Bard 3 copy bard scrolls into the wizard spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, bard

Since I have levels in Bard, can I copy (for example) *mass cure wounds* (a level 5 bard spell that isn't also a wizard spell) from a bard scroll into my spell book?

Could I do this idea with 3 levels in Cleric instead of in Bard?

Comment: The second question you had (about using this to cast higher-level class spells than you normally can) is already asked & answered in [Can a multiclass Wizard use any Wizard spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50424), so I edited it out of the post.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### No; you can only copy wizard spells into your spellbook

The ["Your Spellbook"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#LearningSpellsof1stLevelandHigher) sidebar states the following about copying spells into your spellbook (emphasis mine):

> When you find **a wizard spell of 1st level or higher**, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a spell level you can prepare and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.

This passage disallows copying spells outside those available to a wizard into the spellbook, regardless of what other classes you've taken levels in.

Answer (score 1):

No. The wizard spell book is an item made to contain only wizard spells, and due to the fact that mass cure wounds is not, indeed, a wizard spell, it couldn't reasonably be copied into a wizard spellbook. The same could be said for any other non-wizard spell.

Comment: Hi Mark, and welcome to RPG.SE. Check out the [tour] to see how we work here. This answer would benefit from citations so that we can take what it's asserting in confidence.

Answer (score -4):

Actually you could copy mass cure wounds because as a wizard / bard all the spells YOU know become both wizard and bard spells to YOU.

Comment: Can you back up this claim with a reference to the rules? Otherwise it's going to be downvoted.

Comment: Especially since a level 14 Wizard / level 3 Bard cannot *know* mass cure wounds since they don't have the Bard level for it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. [All answers must be supported by evidence/experience](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/33569); please edit your answer to support it by citing the relevant rules/evidence.

Comment: (...Though that may be hard to do, since I'm pretty sure the rules don't say anything of the sort. In fact, the [multiclass spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules say exactly the opposite: "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class. [...] Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.")