# Can a level 2 Wizard with 1st Level Spells use a Spell Scroll with a 3rd Level spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wizard

We are just starting out, and our level 2 Wizard acquired a scroll of [Leomund's Tiny Hut](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Leomund%27s_Tiny_Hut), a 3rd level spell. Given that she is nowhere near being able to use this right now under normal circumstances, can she do anything with it? Or just hang on to it for a few months?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your wizard can do two things: wait to learn the spell or cast the spell by succeeding on a spellcasting check.

### Learning the Spell

When you reach 5th level (and gain access to 3rd level spells) you can copy it into your spellbook using the rules on p.114 of the PHB.

### Casting the Spell

At any time you can attempt to cast it using the rules on p.200 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (DMG). If you are 5th level you can do this automatically, however:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

For a 3rd level spell the DC is 13, so for a 2nd level caster with a 16-17 Intelligence (+5) you need an 8 or better.

Whether you are successful or not the spell is *gone* and you now have a blank scroll rather than a spell scroll.

Comment: In your example you actually need a 10+ to successfully cast the spell from the scroll. a 16 INT only gives you a +3 and according to mike mearls https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/09/13/do-i-add-my-proficiency-bonus-to-ability-check-if-i-use-a-scroll-of-a-higher-level/ you don't get your PB.

Answer (score 23):

She can cast *Leomund's Tiny Hut* with it. From the DMG, page 200:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

However, [she cannot learn the spell from the scroll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50424/15469). So it's up to her to decide whether she uses the scroll to cast the spell, or saves it for when it will let her learn the spell permanently.