# Does a multiclassed wizard start with a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, equipment

If I multiclass into Wizard, do I automatically begin with a spellbook?

I'm looking for support within the written rules. Designer intent is a consideration, but their intent should be well supported in order to be accepted. If using intent, please review the tweet's logic within the rules to support it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Yes, you are granted a spellbook by your spellcasting.

Spellcasting (PHB 114):

> As a student of arcane magic, you have a spellbook containing spells
>   that show the first glimmerings of your true power.

So you have a spellbook, disregarding how you got it.

Class Features (PHB 164):

> When you gain a new level in a class, you get its features for that
>   level.

Spellcasting is a class feature that has additional rules tied to it.

Spellcasting (PHB 164):

> Your capacity for spellcasting depends partly on your combined levels
>   in all your spellcasting classes and partly on your individual levels
>   in those classes.

As the additional rules do not state that you lose any spellbook granted, you have one.

---

### So what about the spellbook that is listed under equipment?

Well, that is also a separate issue (which most GM's dutifully ignore).

Your spellbook is part of the spellcasting class feature, which is a separate instance from your starting equipment. Your starting equipment is not a class feature granted by multiclassing [PHB errata V2.0 page 2](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)

> You don’t, however, receive the class’s starting equipment,

**So what is your new spellbook that you get due to your spellcasting feature?**

> Your spellbook is a unique compilation of spells, with its own
>   decorative flourishes and margin notes. It might be a plain,
>   functional leather volume that you received as a gift from your
>   master, a finely bound gilt-edged tome you found in an ancient
>   library, or even a loose collection of notes scrounged together after
>   you lost your previous spellbook in a mishap.

Well, it could be lots of things, [Rubiksmoose](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28591/rubiksmoose) phrases it nicely:

> you can use almost anything as a spellbook even things like metal
>   sheets and carved rocks in a bag.

Comment: D&D Beyond seems to follow this interpretation. Creating a character and multiclassing into wizard does not give you a spellbook equipment but still allows you to use the spellbook features [character test here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/13574480). This is naturally just because someone programmed it like that (perhaps even unintentionally) but I still found it interesting.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes.

According to Jeremy Crawford on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/983491341052071936), the spellbook is a feature of the class, and is therefore gained upon taking a level in Wizard. How you explain it in-game is between the DM and the player to work out:

> The wizard's Spellcasting feature says you have a spellbook with six
> 1st-level wizards spells in it of your choice. That means you have a
> spellbook with those six spells in it. Work out with your DM how you
> acquired that wondrous book. #DnD

Comment: Can you support this outside of purely JC. He gives some insight into his mind, but the tweets aren't official rules/rulings. I'd prefer answers to be focused more on the written rules.

Comment: As Crawford's tweets are no longer considered official rulings, this answer will probably benefit from quoting/investigating the specific rules and how they support the conclusion in a bit more detail.

Comment: Also note that sageadvice.eu is NOT Sage Advice from WoTC. It's just a guy who consolidated designer tweets.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing the PHB text for the wizard's Spellcasting feature ("you have a spellbook...")

Comment: I'm also not asking how to narrate it, just whether or not it's possible.

Comment: I wonder how many other classes have a part of their "feature" that can be stolen...

Comment: @Slagmoth It's possible that you could consider any spell focus/component pouch to also be an issue. Or taking weapons away from a martial?

Comment: @NautArch I don't think the concepts quite equate. Being proficient in something is a feature but having the item with which you are proficient is equipment. I have had PC's spellbooks destroyed or stolen in the past, same with weapons for a fighter but it is not as devastating to a fighter as it is to a wizard. I just think of features as things you can't have taken away. The way spellcasting is worded for the wizard is a bit off in my mind is all I am saying.

Comment: @Slagmoth Fully agree. It's a fairly awful mechanic, especially if the DM utilizes it without having safe backup options available for whatever reason. But if you do, then why have it at all?