# Can I as a Wizard multiclass learn higher level spells through Spell Scrolls despite not being able to cast them?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, spell-slots

I am an Arcane Trickster 3/Wizard 2. Based on the multiclass spell slot table, I have two 2nd level spell slots. These are my questions though:

1. **Can I copy the Misty Step spell, a level 2 spell, into my Wizard spell book despite being unable to cast it as a Wizard or Arcane Trickster?**
2. **And can I use the copied spell to create Misty Step scrolls?**

Comment: To clarify, you're asking if you can (1) scribe a scroll of a higher level than you can cast into your spellbook and (2) craft a spell scroll based on that spell, correct?

Comment: Related : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159656/can-a-wizard-copy-a-wizard-spell-into-their-spellbook-that-they-arent-high-enou

Comment: This should not have been closed. The linked answer is relevant to the title, but does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 5):

### No on all counts

**You cannot copy the spell into your spellbook**. You can only copy spells into your spell book that you can prepare (p. 114, *PHB*, inset box Your Spellbook):

> ***Copying a Spell into the Book***. When you find a wizard spell of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook **if it is of a spell level you can prepare** and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.

The multiclassing rules say:

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

As a 2nd level wizard, you cannot prepare 2nd level spells. Because you cannot prepare the spell, you cannot copy the spell into your book. Arcane Trickster's spellcasting feature does not use a spellbook, so you also cannot copy it as an Arcane Trickster.

**You also cannot scribe scrolls of the spell**. The Crafting Magic Item rules (*DMG*, p. 128) say:

> The character must also be a spellcaster with spell slots and **must be able to cast any spells that the item can produce**.

As you cannot cast the spell with either of your two classes, you cannot craft a magic item that can produce the spell, such as a *spell scroll*.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* provides updated optional rules for scribing scrolls (p. 133), but it also demands that "*the character must have the spell prepared, or it must be among the character's known spells, in order to scribe a scroll of that spell.*", so you also could not scribe it using these alternate rules.